# How To Break Up EntityReferenceCollection?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am writing a method that would break up the EntityReferenceCollection into a specified chunk size. I have the code for a list but no idea how to do so for an EntityReferenceCollection PLEASE HELP!

```c#
public static List<List<T>> Split<T>(List<T> collection, int size)
        {
            var chunks = new List<List<T>>();
            var chunkCount = collection.Count() / size;

            if (collection.Count % size > 0)
                chunkCount++;

            for (var i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++)
                chunks.Add(collection.Skip(i * size).Take(size).ToList());

            return chunks;
        }
```

I am trying to do a bulk delete:

```c#
string fetchXml = @" <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                        <entity name='new_units'>
                            <link-entity name='new_alterunitorder' from ='new_orderlineid' to = 'new_unitsid' >
                                <attribute name='new_alterunitorderid' />
                                <filter type='and'>
                                    <condition attribute='new_orderdate' operator='on-or-after' value='" + startDate.ToShortDateString() + @"' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_orderdate' operator='on-or-before' value='" + endDate.ToShortDateString() + @"' />
                                    <condition attribute='new_orderlineid' operator='eq' uiname='" + uiName + @"' uitype='new_units' value='" + unitOrderId + @"' />
                                </filter>
                            </link-entity>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch>";

                    EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));

                    var entRefCollection = new EntityReferenceCollection();

                    foreach (var id in result.Entities)
                    {
                        var reference = id.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_alterunitorderid");
                        entRefCollection.Add(reference);
                    }

                    if(entRefCollection.Count < 1000)
                    {
                        Bulk.BulkDelete(service, entRefCollection);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Bulk.BulkDelete(service, entRefCollection_one);  //1st half of EntityReferenceCollection
                        Bulk.BulkDelete(service, entRefCollection_two);

                    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for this method to return a `<List<List<EntityReference>>` or a `List<EntityReferenceCollection>` ? You can access an item in the EntityReferenceCollection as `myCollection[i]` with `i` being the index of the item. With this syntax you can loop through the EntityReferenceCollection and split it up.

Comment: I need to pass the split up entitycollection to BulkDelete Twice.. I can only pass a datacollection, right? So I need to split up one EntityReferenceCollection into two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for that update. I also just posted an answer on your other question about bulk delete.

In short, if you're going to do this yourself in code you could use the FetchXML paging cookie to download batches of 1000 records and then do multi-request batches of 1000 deletes as well.

I find the paging in LINQ to be a bit friendlier than FetchXML, so you might want to switch to a [LINQ query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328028.aspx), and page through that via the same type of syntax you're using in your List example: `Skip(i * size).Take(size)`

Or, as I posted on the other question you can submit a bulk delete job.

Comment: Honestly I don't even know LINQ that well and prefer to avoid it for now... My first question is does Bulk.BulkDelete(service, entRefCollection) work in the first if statement? if so, why can't I just split the entRefCollection into two Datacollection<T> lists and pass each one to BulkDelete?!! I don't need to worry about paging anymore, I restricted contracts to generate max two thousand records, so I will never need to delete more!

Comment: If you're limiting it to 2000 records, all the gyrations to do "bulk" processing are probably overkill. You can just get them all with a single fetch and then loop through them individually. If you were doing 20K or 200K bulk processing would make sense. By the way, where did you get `Bulk.BulkDelete` from? We'd have to see to code before I could tell you what it does. Overall, I'd say you might want to keep things simple.

Comment: I created a class called bulk and used the Bulkdelete method you provided earlier, the one that can do only 1000 per call and can only be called twice.

Comment: I know its kind of overkill, but I'm building a synchronous plugin where the user has to wait for the delete to finish... If we use Bulkdelete twice it would be great. I just need two separate Datacollection lists generated from the entityreferencecollections so I can pass them to Bulkdelete.

Comment: Interesting. Having a user wait for a synchronous plugin that deletes 2000 records could get dicey. Is that plugin registered in the sandbox? How long does it typically take to run in your environment?

Comment: This is for a contract update. So say that 2 months into the contract, the client wants to add lines, I would delete all records from the current date to the end of the contract. Then I would make new records from the current date to the end of the contract. Maximum possible records that would need to be removed is actually 1999. Yes, the plugin is registered in sandbox. I don't know how long it takes since i haven't tested it yet!

Comment: Sandbox operations have a max-time limit of 2 minutes